# Kotlin: ClassCastException when casting double to integer?

Tags: kotlin, casting

I need to do a for loop in Kotlin:

```
for (setNum in 1..(savedExercisesMap[exerciseKey] as HashMap<*, *>)["sets"] as Int){
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I wouldn't think this would be an issue. Is there a reason why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: try `toInt()` function, e.g. `(savedExercisesMap[exerciseKey] as HashMap<*, *>)["sets"].toInt()`

Comment: @Sergey unresolved reference...

Comment: could you please provide entire code: `savedExercisesMap`, `exerciseKey` etc.

Comment: The exception message is quite clear: you're trying to cast a Double to an Integer. You can of course cast it to a Double, and then call toInt() on that Double to transform it to an Int, but really, this shows a big design issue in your code: if it's supposed to be an Int, why is it a Double? And most importantly, Kotlin being a type-safe language, why do you need so many casts to do what you want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Casting from `Double` to `Int` will never succeed using `as` keyword. They both extend `Number` class and neither extends the other, so this cast is neither downcasting or upcasting. To convert a double to int in Kotlin you should use `.toInt()` function.

```
val aDouble: Double = 2.22222
//val anInt = aDouble as Int // wrong
val anInt = aDouble.toInt() // correct
```